# Is there a way  prevent to put duplicates?

Tags: php, template-lite

I have a query like this:

```
  $mp = NCore::db()->query("SELECT DISTINCT TOWN,NAME FROM CINEMA WHERE CITY_ID = ".$_POST['town']."");
```

What i want is that something like this

Greenville
 .....
 .....
 .....
Franklin
.......
.......

I have below code, but it writes all town names.What i want is that i want to write town name only one time.Is there a way to do this?

```
<h1>Son eklenen sinema salonları</h1>
    <form action="#" method="post">
        <table border ="1">


            {foreach value=mp from=$mpbycity}

            <tr>
                <td> 


                    {$mp.TOWN}
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    {$mp.NAME}
                </td>
            </tr>

            {/foreach}
        </table>

</form>
```

[image]

I want to show you the duplicates. Is there a way to print only one time?

Comment: Which is the schema of this table? Which is the type of TOWN? Maybe,  if you're using an ORM, it's an object...

Answer (score 0):

```
$mp = NCore::db()->query("SELECT TOWN, NAME FROM CINEMA WHERE CITY_ID = ".$_POST['town']." GROUP BY TOWN, NAME");
```

Comment: can the `DISTINCT` keyword be also used?

Comment: SELECT DISTINCT should do exactly the same than this GROUP BY... but as he's using an ORM, I'm not sure what's going on under the hood... thought it wouldn't hurt to try the same thing writing it differently.

Comment: DISTINCT can only be use either for TOWN or NAME, not for both

Answer (score 0):

```
  $mp = NCore::db()->query("SELECT TOWN,NAME FROM CINEMA WHERE CITY_ID = ".$_POST['town']." GROUP BY TOWN");
```

Only if you want unique TOWN

if it is for both NAME and TOWN

```
$mp = NCore::db()->query("SELECT TOWN,NAME FROM CINEMA WHERE CITY_ID = ".$_POST['town']." GROUP BY TOWN,NAME");
```